# int var = null; невозможно?

Tags: c#

Задался таким вопросом

```
int x = null;
```

Естественно нельзя, а можно ли обойти как-то?

Comment: встречный вопрос - а зачем?

Answer (score 10):

```
int? x = null;
```

Не подойдет? Вот статья: [типы, допускающие значения NULL (руководство по программированию на C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

Comment: то что нужно, а что это значит "?"

Comment: первый раз такой вариант вижу в шарпе =)

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx][1]

[http://hitfounder.livejournal.com/20792.html][2]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx
  [2]:  http://hitfounder.livejournal.com/20792.html

Comment: я тоже, просто увидел такой вопрос, вот и решил попробовать и можно ли, погуглив оказалось что это специальный вариант записи для int == null

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, низя потому что примитивы не объекты, потому они и должны быть объявлены обязательно. Если очень хочется - есть враперы над ними.

Answer (score -1):

Как я помню то **NULL** тип переменной int не может принимать, обычно присваивают значение равное 0.

Comment: @UserTest упомянул о существовании `Nullable<T>` и её обёртке `T?`